# Why is my Google Maps API v2 still working

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have a google map on my site for showing visitors where events are held, in the back end of the site, the user can enter an address find the location and then drag the marker to the specific location. For this i am using Google Maps APi v2 but it is still working.

Should it not of stopped working after the API was made redundant? Or how long will it still work for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to google ([here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference)):

> As of November 19, 2013, all applications requesting v2 are served a special, wrapped version of the v3 API instead. We expect this wrapped version of the API to work for most simple maps, but we strongly encourage you to migrate to the v3 API immediately.